# Regular Pentagon with Exterior Triangle - find angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, symmetry

This is a 5 point question in a math competition.  I managed to get the 7 point questions right but got stumped by this one:

In the given figure, ABCDE is a regular pentagon. $$AD=AF$$ and $$\angle DAF = 56^\circ$$  What is $x$?

[image: Figure from the math competition]

I suspect that they told us $$AD = AF$$ because they want us to consider triangle ADF as isosceles, i.e. $$\angle ADF = \angle AFD = 62^\circ$$.

Here is what I have done so far - still missing some info before I can get to $x$.

[image: Work I've done so far]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated -thanks

Comment: I hope you are not attempting to use this site for cheating purposes. We generally do not tolerate that sort of behavior.

Comment: In addition, it is not at all clear what exactly you have already tried. I strongly suggest you add more details regarding the specific problem and your attempt at solving it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and not trying to cheat at all.  I should have said this is from a Mathcon practice test published on the official Mathcon site.  Stackexchange won’t let me paste the image of the figure, it will only let me link it like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hthqM.png.  And here is the link of the work I have done:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC7C5.jpg. I thought they were included in the original post but maybe not.

Comment: @GS44731 Due to certain issues (I believe it's things like spamming, inappropriate images, etc.), you need a certain minimum reputation (I believe it's $10$) to be able to insert images into your question. Nonetheless, I've done that for you, as well as make a few small corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made a good start, with everything you've shown being correct, but rather than adding the line $DF$ as you did, it's more useful to add $AC$ instead to the original diagram, as shown below,

[image: Figure from OP with line AC added, as well as several degree measures]

Since $|AE| = |ED|$, then $\triangle AED$ is isosceles. Since $\measuredangle DEA = \frac{3(180^{\circ})}{5} = 108^{\circ}$ then, as you've shown,

$$\measuredangle ADE = \measuredangle DAE = \frac{180^{\circ} - 108^{\circ}}{2} = 36^{\circ}$$

Due to the symmetry of a regular pentagon, $|AD| = |AC|$, so $\triangle ACD$ is also isosceles. Thus, as you've also already determined,

$$\measuredangle ADC = \measuredangle ACD = 108^{\circ} - 36^{\circ} = 72^{\circ}$$

This means

$$\measuredangle CAD = 180^{\circ} - 2\times 72^{\circ} = 36^{\circ} \;\; \to \;\; \measuredangle CAF = 56^{\circ} - 36^{\circ} = 20^{\circ}$$

Next, since $|AD| = |AC| = |AF|$, then $\triangle ACF$ is isosceles. Therefore,

$$\measuredangle AFC = \measuredangle ACF = \frac{180^{\circ} - 20^{\circ}}{2} = 80^{\circ}$$

In addition,

$$\measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle EDA = 36^{\circ}$$

Thus, we finally get

$$x = \measuredangle ACF - \measuredangle ACB = 80^{\circ} - 36^{\circ} = 44^{\circ}$$

Comment: Thanks @John Omielan.  Didn’t think of all diagonals being equal in a regular pentagon!